# An HttpURLconnection in asynctask get not working

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have been working on this for awhile now, I am trying to just send a simple get request to a server to insert a name a user types into a database. I know the PHP to receive the request is not the problem because I can simply put a parameter in the url browser and it is working. I have tried both using AsyncTask and just creating a new Thread as well to open the connection. Here is my code which is calling the AsyncTask - the URL is correct I've doubled check it like 10 times -

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            //gets the value of the user's textbox
            String valueOfText = theText.getText().toString();
            //creating the parameter to add to URL
            String params = "name=" + valueOfText;
            //url to request 
            String request = "http://www.southardsoftware.com/name.php?" + params;
            //look at other class for more info
            SenderAsync theSyncer = new SenderAsync(request);
            theSyncer.execute();
        }
```

And here is the AsyncTask class that's relevant -

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        //creating a URL to use
        URL url = new URL(request);
        //connecting to URL. The parameters are literally in the URL to use
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        //whatever logging here
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is it a problem that the class is created in an onclick method? I have tried adding a for loop that runs 20000 times right after .execute() just so there is more code to run, and also putting the Thread to sleep (some advice I looked up simply said the activity might end before it gets done so I tried that).

PS I am actually creating this as a mini tutorial for teammates of mine so pardon the obvious comments...

UPDATE - since the whole class is wanted...

```
public class SenderAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
//the URL from MainActivity
private String request;


public SenderAsync(String request2) {
    request = request2;

}
```

The only thing in is a constructor which takes the URL as an argument

Comment: There problem appers? have you tried to do it in a browser? do you have any stack error in android log?

Comment: Try to use more comfortable library: jsoup.org

Comment: add whole SenderAsync class...

Comment: also check your url I only pasted this `http://www.southardsoftware.com/name.php` in browser and it says inserts done

Comment: There are no exceptions happening and no errors...it just doesn't seem to execute

Comment: Yea I know it is working in the browser when i use a parameter

Comment: That's because the php is still working...it is just entering an empty string into the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you are only interested in the server side effect and not in the response, you have to invoke `getInputStream()`. It triggers the actual request. Otherwise the server will not receive anything.

See the [HttpURLConnection class overview](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) for more details

Comment: This seems to have been the problem. I very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

`request` variable created locally inside `onClick()`.
 In `doInBackgroud()` you should use `URL url = new URL(params[0]);`

Comment: I think you are right but he didnt write where error appear:)

Comment: no error is appearing...i am passing the URL as a parameter in the constructor for the class